# AngularJS : Accessing a parent scope from a child directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

The following code does not work. Apparently I cannot access `someFunction()` from `child-dir`.

Is it a matter of accessing a parent scope from a child directive? How to do it, when the child directive comes from an external library?

Angular/HTML:

```
<parent-dir ng-controller="parentCtrl">
  <child-dir ng-click="someFunction()">
  </child-dir>
</parent-dir>
```

JS:

```
.controller('parentCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.someFunction = function() {
    console.log('hello');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to provide your directive here.  Likely you are using an isolate scope which breaks the parent child chain of scopes.  My guess is you have something like this:

```
angular.module('module').directive('childDir', [function () {
  return {
    scope: {
      // Having scope defined as an object makes it an 'isolate' scope
      // and breaks the chain between this scope and the parent scope.
    }
  };
}];
```

To fix this you can get access to the parent controller directly like so:

```
angular.module('module').directive('childDir', [function () {
  return {
    require: '^parentCtrl',
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, parentCtrl) {
      $scope.someFunction = parentCtrl.someFunction;  // of course this only works if you make someFunction a public function on the parentCtrl
    },
    scope: {
      // Having scope defined as an object makes it an 'isolate' scope
      // and breaks the chain between this scope and the parent scope.
    }
  };
}];
```

Or you can make your scope non-isolate by either not returning a 'scope' key in your directive definition or setting it like { scope: true } (which will give you a new child scope).  Another option is to break the isolate barrier by directly accessing the parent scope (rather than relying on prototypal inheritance) like so: $scope.$parent.someFunction().

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `child-dir` has created an isolated scope from `parent-dir`.

In your directive declaration if you specify scope as equal to true, you'll have access to the parent scope. You'd do it like this:

```
directive("child-dir", [
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: true,
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
                  }
            };
       }
]);
```